# How can I measure time taken by a process in C using Linux System Call gettimeofday()?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I'm trying to find how much time the process / function took to find the solution. I am asked to do it using gettimeofday() Linux System Call.
Any help?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read the man page?

Comment: It is not a system call.

Comment: `gettimeofday` is not the solution to get time taken by a process.

Comment: Do you want CPU time used or wall time elapsed?  They’re different.  And there are reasons to prefer `clock_gettime()` to `gettimeofday()`.  (There are also some reasons, increasingly less compelling reasons, to use `gettimeofday()` instead.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my tested code snipped:

```
struct timeval t1, t2;
double elapsedTime;

// start timer
gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

// do something
// ...

// stop timer
gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);

// compute and print the elapsed time in millisec
elapsedTime = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000.0;      // sec to ms
elapsedTime += (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000.0;   // us to ms
fprintf(stderr, "elapsedTime = %5.3fms \n", elapsedTime);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!